# POST Jquery AJAX error 500

Tags: javascript, php

I have a strange problem. Yesterday everything worked fine.

I have a simple php file, as follows:

```
<?php

  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

  echo json_encode(['messageType' =>
  'success','message'=>$_POST['key']);

  die();

  }
```

And js file with Ajax query:

```
$.ajax({

          dataType: "json",

           type: "POST",

          url: 'get.php',

          data: {key: 'a'},

          success: function(data) {

                  alert(data.message)

          },

          error: function(data) {

          alert ('error');}

      });
```

When the  field 'key' is set to 1 character (eg. 'a'), I get an error 500 from the server. But if I change it to at least 3 characters everything works just fine.

The problem's begun occurring suddenly on several independent servers.

Comment: I don't know what could be but I don't think the semicolon after messageType should be there.

Comment: Right. In original file there is no ;

Comment: A `500` is either caused by php or by your web server. You have to check what the php and the web server show in the error log for this request. Without the corresponding information in the logs its not really possible to guess, why it would work with more than three chars, but would fail for less then three.

Comment: 500 means go check your server logs instead of looking for code. Go check your endpoint get.php

Comment: i can help you, but if you want to allow all method, i will create simple ajax and how to respond it, but i not use JSON, and why must use JSON?

Comment: check the network tab and query parameters to verify whether the `a` is passed correctly or not

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Error 500 means there should be something wrong with your PHP Endpoint.
At first remove the semicolon and try if it works:

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    echo json_encode(['messageType' =>'success','message'=>$_POST['key']);
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] variable available (which is server dependent) you will get a 500 right from the start. The json_encode was also not working due to syntax.

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['key'])) {
  echo json_encode(array('messageType' => 'success','message'=>$_POST['key']));
  die();
  }
?>
```